# Existing file not appending new record

Tags: python, file, append

I am trying to create a file as the header and then open it later to append new records, but it seems I am not doing something correctly, does anyone have an idea?

here is the code below:

I have tried it in several ways to no avail.

```
file = 'Quizdata5.txt'
users = {}

def header():
    headers = ("USERID      LOGIN-NAME      SURNAME        NAME       AGE  "
               "       YEAR-GROUP     SEX    USERNAME\n")
    with open(file, 'w') as file1:
        file1 .write(headers)
        file1.close()

def newUser():
    global users
    global header
    global createLogin
    global createPassw
    global surname
    global name
    global  age
    global  y_group
    global  sex
    global z1

    createLogin = input("Create login name: ")
    if createLogin in users: # check if login name exists
        print("\nLogin name already exist, please choose a different name!\n")
    else:
        createPassw = input("Create password: ")
        users[createLogin] = createPassw # add login and password
    #return (users[createLogin])
    surname = input("Pls enter your surname: ")
    name = input("Pls enter ur name: ")
    age = input("Pls enter your age: ")
    y_group = int(input("Please enter your year group: "))
    sex =input("Please enter your sex: ")
    print("\nUser created!\n")
    print("*********************************")
    print(" Your Name is\t" + name, "and it starts with: " + name[0] + "\n")
    z1 = createPassw[:3] + age
    print(" Your Username is:\t ", z1)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    header()
    while newUser():
        with open(file, 'a') as file2:
            rows = ("{:8}    {:8}        {:8}        {:8}       {:8}    {:8}"
                    "     {:8}      {:8} \n".format(createLogin, createPassw,
                                                    surname, name, age,
                                                    y_group, sex, z1))
             file2.write(rows.split())
        file2.close()
        #enter code here
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting.

Comment: Hi Grace. I think it would be best if you broke your code down into smaller pieces. Start with one small part, test it and fix until it works, and then go to the next small part. Trying to troubleshoot all this at once is not good. And your code formatting is not working when cut and pasting for testing.

Comment: What is the error? Is there an error?

Comment: There is no error,it runs smoothly, but just wont append the new row record to the existing header file

Answer (score 0):

Working version below. Note that I changed your `input` statements to raw_input. I'm using Python 2.7. Main things needed:

1. a choice to exit outside AND inside the while loop
2. build a list for existing users for the existing username check
3. fixing your formatting for row
4. Not splitting your row when you write it

Seems to be working now and ready for more improvements. Build a little and test until working, then build more - saves a ton of time!

```
file = 'Quizdata5.txt'
users = {}

def header():
    headers = "USERID    LOGIN-NAME    SURNAME    NAME    AGE    YEAR-GROUP    SEX    USERNAME\n"
    with open(file, 'r') as file1:
        firstLine = file1.readline()
        print firstLine
        if firstLine == headers:
            print 'Headers present'
            return
    with open(file, 'w') as file1:
            file1.write(headers)

def newUser():
    userList = []

    with open(file, 'r') as file1:
        Lines = file1.readlines()
        for line in Lines[1:]:
            lineArray = line.split('    ')
            userList.append(lineArray[0])
        print userList

    global users
    global header
    global createLogin
    global createPassw 
    global surname 
    global name
    global  age
    global  y_group
    global  sex
    global z1

    createLogin = raw_input("Create login name or enter 'exit' to quit: ")
    if createLogin == 'exit':
        return False

    while createLogin in userList: # check if login name exists
        print("\nLogin name already exist, please choose a different name!\n")
        createLogin = raw_input("Create login name or enter 'exit' to quit: ")
        createLogin = createLogin.strip()
        if createLogin == 'exit':
            print('Goodbye for now.')
            return False
    createPassw = raw_input("Create password: ")
    users[createLogin] = createPassw # add login and password
    # return (users[createLogin])
    surname = raw_input("Pls enter your surname: ")
    name = raw_input("Pls enter ur name: ")
    age = raw_input("Pls enter your age: ")
    y_group = int(raw_input("Please enter your year group: "))
    sex = raw_input("Please enter your sex: ")
    print("\nUser created!\n") 
    print("*********************************")
    print(" Your Name is\t" + name, "and it starts with: " + name[0] + "\n")
    z1 = createPassw[:3] + age
    print(" Your Username is:\t ", z1)
    return True

if __name__ =='__main__':
    header()    
    while newUser() == True:
        with open(file, 'a') as file2:
            row ="{a}    {b}    {c}    {d}    {e}    {f}    {g}    {h}\n".format(
                    a=createLogin, b=createPassw, c=surname, d=name, e=age, f=y_group, g=sex, h=z1)
            file2.write(row)
```

Comment: Hi Thom Ives Thanks alot, the solution is working fine, but the problem is, each time  i run the program, it erases the existing file and creates a new one. is there a way of permanently creating the header column once and appends new row for each new run. secondly, the exit is not working. In my former code i have tried quit and it didnt work either. if you dont mind i can give you the entire original  with other module  code so that you see if you know an alternative route

Comment: DOH! I needed to test more myself. Broke it down into little pieces. I left some print statements in that I used for troubleshooting. Try it now.

Comment: Thank you so much Thom, I have not tested yet but it looks like the real thing. the idea of reading the existing file to confirm if there is already a header is very important. Thank you so much

Comment: Great. Think about creating a class to hold this. It will make your code ... "more elegant". Work to find ways to refactor it over time.

Comment: Yea i will do, but do you have ideas about python dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Without just rewriting your code outright, your problem is the line

```
while newUser():
```

This means call `newUser()`, and execute the indented code *only* if the return value of `newUser()`, evaluated as a boolean, returns `True`. That is `bool(newUser()) is True`.

Now the questions are

a) What does `newUser()` return and,
b) What does `bool()` mean?

First b: All objects in Python have some "boolean" value associated with it, `True` or `False`. For a lot of built-in types their boolean evaluation makes sense. For example the integer `0` is treated as `False` in a boolean context, while any non-zero integer is treated as `True`. This is the case in most any programming language with some exceptions.

Similarly an empty list `[]` is `False` in a boolean context (which is why we can write things like `if not my_list: ...` to test if a list is empty) while any non-empty list is treated as `True` and so on.

As for a:

Your `newUser()` function doesn't explicitly return *and any* result, because you don't have a `return` statement (Tom's solution added some). What you want to do is return a `True`-ish value when a new user is added, and a `False`-ish value when no new users are to be added. But since you don't return anything, in fact, the default return value for functions if Python, if you don't explicitly `return`, is a value called `None` and it is always `False`.

So the end result is that the code under your `while` statement is never run.

If you're ever in doubt about what your code is doing walk through it line by line and see exactly what it's doing--what functions are returning and what values are being assigned to variables--by using the `pdb` debugger (Google will direct you quickly to some good tutorials). With Python in particular there's no reason to ever be in the dark about what your code is actually doing.